# ProgressDialog while refreshing a ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView populated by a SimpleAdapter, which gets values from an ArrayList of HashMaps. The arraylist is built by a method `load()` that fetches data from a site of mine. I have a menu option that allows to refresh data by fetching them again and calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it actually works fine, updating the arraylist and refreshing the ListView as well. Now, it takes a few seconds for `load()` to establish the http connection and get the data so I wanted to set up a ProgressDialog to inform the user of the ongoing process. I know I can't put the ProgressDialog on the ui thread where `load()` works, so I tried with an AsyncTask. It works fine, showing the dialog while the new data are being fetched and passed to the adapter, but it also adds a problem: the ListView doesn't refresh the displayed items anymore, unless I scroll the modified list item out of the screen and back, then it would show the new content. What can I do to have both the ProgressDialog and the refresh of the list contents?
This is the code with the ProgressDialog in the AsyncTask (edits data but doesn't trigger list refresh on screen):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.update: {         
        loading.show();  //the ProgressDialog
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> loadingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {                 
                load(); //fetching data, takes a while
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {                                     
                loading.dismiss();
            }

        };          
        loadingTask.execute();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
        return true;
    }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the code that would refresh the ListView as well as the data behind (but won't let me set up a ProgressDialog):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.update: {                                                         
        load();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                     
        return true;
    }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `onPreExecute()` of **AsycTask** and `show()` `ProgressDialog` from it. and put `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`      in `onPostExecute()` of **AsyncTask**.

Like,

```
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> loadingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {                                     
            loading.show();  //the ProgressDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {                 
            load(); //fetching data, takes a while
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                        
            loading.dismiss();
        }

    };          
    loadingTask.execute();      
    return true;
```

Comment: also move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem - My typing mistake I update answer. Thanks for it.